# TextureViewを継承したViewをFragment内に配置し、何度か表示すると Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)が出る

Tags: android

下記のようなTextureViewを継承したViewを作成してFragment内に配置し、Fragmentの表示・リプレースを何度か繰り返すと　Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)　が出て終了します。

試したことは

- 表示・リプレースを繰り返した時、数回でFatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)となる場合もあれば、ずっと繰り返してやっと出る場合もある。
- 表示上の都合でSurfaceViewからTextureViewに変更したのですが、SurfaceViewでは同じようなこと（オーバーライドしたrunメソッド内でCanvasにループして描画する）をしてもFatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)は出なかった。
- android:largeHeapの設定をしても現象は変わらず、MemoryMonitorとMemoryAnalyzerで調査を行いましたがメモリリークはないようです。

よろしくお願いします。

---

### 追記

エミュレータで試したところ現象を再現できませんでした。

現象が発生する端末
 - Xperia Z3 compact

発生しない端末

- エミュレータ　Genymotion

---

参考にしたサイト
http://dev.classmethod.jp/slide/introduction_textureview_20130116/

---

TextureViewを継承したView：

```
public class TextureAnimation extends TextureView  implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener,Runnable{


static final long FPS = 60;
static final long FRAME_TIME = 1000 / FPS;
static final int BALL_R = 40;
Thread thread;

private float scale;

public TextureAnimation(Context context){
    super(context);
    setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
                                      int height) {
    thread=new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    thread=null;
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
                                        int height) {
}
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas = null;


    long loopCount = 0;
    long waitTime = 0;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


    //アニメーション用のループ
    while (thread != null) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();


        paint.setAntiAlias(true);


        // Ball
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);


            try {
                loopCount++;
                canvas = this.lockCanvas();

                scale = scale + 0.025f;

                //透明色で前回の描画を消す
                canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

                //玉の描画
                canvas.save();
                canvas.scale(scale, scale,50, 50);
                canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, BALL_R,paint);
                canvas.restore();

                this.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);


                waitTime = (loopCount * FRAME_TIME)
                        - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

                if (scale > 1) {
                    scale = 0;
                }


                if (waitTime > 0) {
                    Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }


    }
}
```

}

Fragmentへの配置

```
textureanim = new TextureAnimation(context);
        frameLayout.addView(textureanim, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MP, MP));
```

Logcat

```
 Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x93f3a5f4 (code=1), thread 5581 (Thread-644)
```

Comment: 暇人の戯言です。
後始末の問題っぽい？気が直感でしました。

候補1:
スレッドの後始末に問題があるかもしれません。
'OnSurfaceTextureDestroyed'で'thread=null'としている箇所が、スレッドの止め方として乱暴なので'Thread.interrupt()'で優しく止めるか、'Thread.stop()'で引っ叩くか、先に実装してはいかがでしょうか。
その場合、Thread.sleep()のCatch内に、ループを抜ける処理が必要です。
マルチスレッドで似たようなエラーを見たことがあるのでthreadが止まってないのかも。

候補2:
フラグメントの後始末に問題があるかもしれません。
[Fatal signal 11 after Fragment animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178300/fatal-signal-11-after-fragment-animation)みたいなことがあるらしいです。

Comment: コメント有難うございます。
候補1・2ともに試してみましたが、現象は変わりませんでした。

Comment: お力になれず、すみません。。。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`run()`メソッド内の描画部分が原因だと思います。

`lockCanvas`〜`unlock`までの間に`Fragment`が廃棄されると`TextureView`のリソース廃棄されている状態でCanvasのメソッドが呼ばれて、描画中に落ちているのではないかと思います。

`lockCanvas`手前〜`unlock`までの間を`synchro(this)`あたりで囲って、`onSurfaceTextureXXXXX()`メソッドの中味も`synchro(this)`あたりで囲ってあげてCanvas描画中にライフサイクルを終わらせないようにしたらどうでしょうか？

Comment: ご対応ありがとうございます。頂いた回答を適用させたところ、正常に動作しました。
surfaceViewは別のwindowを作る関係で、描画中に落ちなかったようです。